# Stop mapbox.js/leaflet.js tooltip re-rendering on each mousemove?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm using Mapbox.js 2.2.1, which is heavily based on Leaflet.js. I've added some custom tooltips to my feature layer on mousemove, using some borrowed code.

They appear OK, but they re-render on each mousemove, which gives a very jerky effect:

```
    _this.orgLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        var closeTooltip;
        layer.on('mousemove', function(e) {
            var layerData = e.target.feature.properties.data;
            var layer = e.target;
            var html = data.name + ' ' + data.date;
            this.popup.setLatLng(e.latlng);
            this.popup.setContent(html);
            // need to adapt this next line...?
            if (!this._map) this.popup.openOn(this.map);
            window.clearTimeout(closeTooltip);
            if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
                layer.bringToFront();
            }
        }, _this);
        layer.on('mouseout', function(e) {
            var _this = this;
            closeTooltip = window.setTimeout(function() {
               _this.map.closePopup();
            }, 100);
        }, _this);
    });
```

I would rather just reset the latlng on each mousemove. What am I doing wrong?

I think the key might be in the line `if (!this._map) this.popup.openOn(this.map);`, which I might need to adapt.